# Footer overlaps content

Tags: html, css, footer, overlap

I have a product gallery website and I am having lots of problems for putting my footer at the bottom of the page. My website is structured:

I have a header, then on the part of the left I have a menu filter, and then on the right I have the image gallery of all the products.

If I define the footer with position: relative the footer doesn't put to the bottom of the page.

If I put the `position:absolute` the footer places to the bottom of the page but then collapse with the content of the page.

How I can solve it?

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.wrapper-gallery {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="generalPage">
  <section>
    <header id="includeHeader"></header>
    <div id="divContent" class="wrapper-gallery">
      <div class="row noPaddingRow">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <ul id="menuFiltre2" class="menuFiltre">
            <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia()"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Veure tot</a></li>
            <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia(8)"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Clothing</a></li>
            <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia(6)"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Jewelley</a></li>
            <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia(7)"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Books</a></li>
            <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia(4)"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Souvenirs</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <div id="p-flex">
            <div class="p-flex">
              <div class="p-flex-in">
                <a href="#" class="leftmenu">
                  <img onerror="this.src=" ..="" images="" img_arti.jpg ""="" alt="t-shirt" class="p-img" src="../loadImg.jsp?codeItem=1" onclick="continueItem(1)">
                  <div class="title-article">Tshirt london</div>
                  <div class="price-article">8.12€</div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <footer id="includeFooter">
          <div class="row" style="background-color:#FFF;">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 redesSocialesPieImg"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 redesSocialesPie"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="background-color:#FFF;">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="footerAdreca">Oxford Street, 10 London · company@gmail.es</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" id="peuCopyright">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
              <div id="copyright"><span>© 2020. All rights reserved. SHOP COMPANY</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
              <div id="logo-footer"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet

Comment: what do you mean by a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems here I see immediately. First you are using a class in your css of `.footer` but there is no such class applied to your footer element in the HTML, your footer element actually has no class at all applied to it at all. You can get rid of the period in front of the selector and just make a selector for the footer element itself. Then simply change the `position` attribute to `fixed`. Like so:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

I just tested in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/yLvEqbW/2f8da97a0676c7ba98a2ed2e8ccfed97) and this solves your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 ways of doing that :

- use absolute positioning, but you'll have to add margin in your container equivalent to footer's height
- use flexbox

Flexbox solution :

```css
html, body, .generalPage, section, .wrapper-gallery {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper-gallery {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
}

footer {

    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.wrapper-gallery{
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="generalPage">
    <section>
        <header id="includeHeader"></header>
        <div id="divContent" class="wrapper-gallery">
            <div class="row noPaddingRow">
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <ul id="menuFiltre2" class="menuFiltre">
                     <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia()"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Veure tot</a></li>
                     <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia(8)"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Clothing</a></li>
                     <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia(6)"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Jewelley</a></li>
                     <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia(7)"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Books</a></li>
                     <li class="familiaMenuNom" onclick="changeFamilia(4)"><a href="#" class="leftmenu">Souvenirs</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <div id="p-flex">
                     <div class="p-flex">
                        <div class="p-flex-in">
                           <a href="#" class="leftmenu">
                              <img onerror="this.src=" ..="" images="" img_arti.jpg""="" alt="t-shirt" class="p-img" src="../loadImg.jsp?codeItem=1" onclick="continueItem(1)">
                              <div class="title-article">Tshirt london</div>
                              <div class="price-article">8.12€</div>
                           </a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
             
            </div>
          <footer id="includeFooter">
                  <div class="row" style="background-color:#FFF;">
                     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 redesSocialesPieImg"></div>
                     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 redesSocialesPie"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" style="background-color:#FFF;">
                     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="footerAdreca">Oxford Street, 10 London · company@gmail.es</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" id="peuCopyright">
                     <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div id="copyright"><span>© 2020. All rights reserved. SHOP COMPANY</span></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div id="logo-footer"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </footer>
        </div>
        
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: So in class footer? You havent add the tag position: absolute

Comment: I have tried your solution. And it doesn't stick to the bottom.

Comment: You have to move the footer out of .row, you said you need it to go to bottom no matter what, not to be sticked